# why is my call to CountCharsAsync blocking the UI?

Tags: c#

I think I am missing something here..
I expected the call to CountCharsAsync() to be non blocking.  But it doesn't seem that way.  When i click on my button nothing happens for the first five seconds.. and the UI gets stuck...

But the second version is fine.

Could someone explain the difference between these two ways...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncAwaitExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Count is : ";
            int count = await CountCharsAsync();
            textBox1.Text += count;

            textBox1.Text += "\r\n-----------\r\n";

            textBox1.Text += "Count is : ";
            Task<int> tsk = new Task<int>(CountChars);
            tsk.Start();
            int count2 = await tsk;
            textBox1.Text += count2;

        }

        private int CountChars()
        {
            int count = 50;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return count;
        }

        private async Task<int> CountCharsAsync()
        {
            int count = 50;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're sleeping the thread.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: That in itself isn't a problem. The problem is what's going on *inside* the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Thread.Sleep` in your async method. That will block whatever thread it's running on... which is still going to be the UI thread. Calling an async method doesn't start a new thread by itself. Other threads can be involved depending on exactly what happens within the method, but until the first `await` expression, the method will execute synchronously on the same thread as the calling code... and your async method doesn't have any await expressions (which should already be giving you a warning).

You should use:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

instead. That's a sort of "asynchronous wait". That way, the UI thread won't be blocked. The task returned by `CountCharsAsync` will complete about 5 seconds later, at which point the next part of `button1_Click` will execute.

Compare that with this code:

```
Task<int> tsk = new Task<int>(CountChars);
tsk.Start();
```

That will execute `CountChars` in the default task scheduler - on the thread pool. Blocking *that* thread doesn't affect the UI at all. (As noted in comments, that's not a good way of starting a task these days. Either call an async method, or use `Task.Run`.)

Comment: I am doing the same thing inside CountChars.. why isn't that one blocking the UI then?..

Comment: @psj01: Refresh my answer - I was just adding a bit about that :)

Comment: so.. the Thread that I put to sleep inside my CountChars is not my main/UI thread ?....

Comment: @psj01: Indeed, it's a thread-pool thread. If you try to update `textBox1.Text` from that method, it should throw an exception (at least when debugging).

Comment: `new Task()` and `task.Start()` is really [very poor way in modern terms to use a task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html).

Comment: @DaisyShipton thanks! makes sense now. I am just learning this bit by bit... so much to go!! :)

Answer (score 0):

While Daisy's answer makes it not block UI, your CountCharsAsync method is "fake" async. If you have Resharper (not sure if this a feature of VS or R#) you will have a warning:

> Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

This is because async Task does not do all the magic - in your case it does absolutetly nothing. Nowhere you make it run on another thread.

Proper implementation would be:

```
private int CountChars()
        {
            int count = 50;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return count;
        }

        private Task<int> CountCharsAsync() // notice no async!
        {
            return Task.Run(CountChars);
        }
```

Daisy's implementation would still block if you replaced Thread.Sleep with for example a for loop to max integer.

My version in fact shifts execution to new thread.